# Adding tuples inside a list into rows using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

i need to add the arr data starting from row 2, column 3

```
|header-----|
|d1|d2|  |  |
|d1|d2|  |  |

arr = [('a','b'),('a','b')]
```

i already tried looping the data and writing using cell but the value seems only supports 1 value at iteration, i think or am i missing something?

```
for x in arr:
 cell(row=2,row=3).value = x
```

error encountered: `cannot convert ('a','b') to excel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

The problem is with your array.

In your loop you are iterating through a list and each of your list element is a tuple containing strings.

So, in you code you'll have this for each element in your loop: `x = ('a','b')`. This element is a tuple (check it with `type(x)` in your loop). You can't assign a tuple to a cell with openpyxl.

---

**Suggested solution**

Use enumerate twice:

```
starting_row = 2
Starting_col = 1
for row, tup in enumerate(arr):
  for col, val in enumerate(tup):
    cell(row=row+starting_row, column=col+starting_col).value = val
    print(row, col, value)
>>> 2 1 a
... 2 2 b
... 3 1 a
... 3 2 b
```

If you want to change the starting row and column, just add values for `row` and `col` parameter inside `cell().value`.

Comment: So the tuple in list is not possible right. that's what i need, i can't change it because the tuple represents the row for my code that's why i'm looping the array to get the rows to edit the excel file and append it there. the blank array only a sample btw, my bad.

Comment: You want to add each tuple in a row in Excel?

Comment: but how can i add it starting from row 2 to col 3? i tried to printing it and the result of both is zero. error showed, row and column values must be at least 1

Comment: I'll change it again, just add to `row` and `column` parameter in `cell().value`

Comment: i think +1 will just add per iteration but will not suffice starting from row 2 to col 3. edited: yes, row is 0, col is 1 as i printed

Comment: thanks henrique. last edit solved my problem. upvote for that